# Variation on linear programming?

Tags: python, algorithm, linear-programming, or-tools

I'm trying to find an existing algorithm for the following problem:

i.e, let's say we have 3 variables, x, y, z (all must be integers).
I want to find values for all variables that MUST match some constraints, such as x+y<4, x<=50, z>x, etc.

In addition, there are extra POSSIBLE constraints, like y>=20, etc. (same as before).
The objective function (which i'm intrested in maximizing its value) is the number of EXTRA constraints that are met in the optimal solution (the "must" constraints + the fact that all values are integers, is a demand. without it, there's no valid solution).

Comment: Just *maximize the sum of indicators* (or their inverse, depends on specifics), where each of your `POSSIBLE` expressions are transformed to some *indicator-based expression* (aka: they have a binary *activation variable = the indicator*). Google integer-programming + indicator variables. This stuff is so common that there should be tons of resources. (*first unfiltered google result:* [Indicator Constraints
in Mixed-Integer Programming](https://www.scipopt.org/workshop2014/scip_lodi.pdf))

Comment: Are you talking about an [integer linear programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using OR-Tools, as the model is integral, I would recommend using CP-SAT, as it offers indicator constraints with a nice API.

The API would be:

```
b = model.NewBoolVar('indicator variable')
model.Add(x + 2 * y >= 5).OnlyEnforceIf(b)

...

model.Maximize(sum(indicator_variables))
```

To get maximal performance, I would recommend using parallelism.

```
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8  # or more on a bigger computer
status = solver.Solve(model)
```